# Will downloading a game on the Xbox Marketplace affect my disc saves?

Tags: xbox-360

I'm planning on selling my copy of Assassin's Creed IV if I download it from the marketplace. However, before I sell it I want to know if my original saves from the disc will exist on the digital version.

Comment: I don't have direct knowledge of AC4, but I've done this with other games before with no ill effects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be fine. If you go to your settings you can see your storage and it will tell you what saved games you have for any given game.

Ie, the saves are on your storage device not your disc or anything so you'll be fine. :)